# How to check multiple arrays for same indexed element, in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

The code below was intended to randomly generate 4 arrays of arranged matches for 4 teams, while positive & negative value assigned to team1~4 for home/away matches. Each array contains 4 values to be shuffled to generate a double round robin tournament, which requires 2*4-2=6 weeks for each team. The #0~#5 elements of each team represent week 1-6 respectively.

The array of each team's schedule is randomized in given range (&team1[0], &team1[5]) and compared, on condition that the same team is not assigned more than once to any of the teams at a same time( #week, or #match ).

The randomizer below works, but the nested loops are stuck in infinite and cannot compare the 4 team arrays. Is there a less clunky way to compare several arrays for same indexed elements in C++?

Edit: Or compare for same absolute values in columns of a 2D array?

```
int main(){

    int S[4][6];  //4teams,index 0-1-2-3,6weeks
    int i,j,k,l,m,flag,size;
    size=6;

    //shuffle each team's schedule
    std::array<int,6> team1{-4,-3,-2,2,3,4};
    std::array<int,6> team2{-4,-3,-1,1,3,4};
    std::array<int,6> team3{-4,-2,-1,1,2,4};
    std::array<int,6> team4{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3};
    std::random_shuffle(&team1[0], &team1[5]);
    std::random_shuffle(&team2[0], &team2[5]);
    std::random_shuffle(&team3[0], &team3[5]);
    std::random_shuffle(&team4[0], &team4[5]);

    //check for overlaps(+-n)
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    l=0;
    m=0;
    flag=false;
    for(int m=0;m<6;++m){

        S[0][m]=team1[m];
        S[1][m]=team2[m];
        S[2][m]=team3[m];
        S[3][m]=team4[m];
    }

    while (i < 6) { //loop through columns

        while(j < 4) {
            while (k < 4) {
                if (abs(S[j][i]) == abs(S[k][i])) {
                    std::random_shuffle(&team1[0], &team1[5]);
                    std::random_shuffle(&team2[0], &team2[5]);
                    std::random_shuffle(&team3[0], &team3[5]);
                    std::random_shuffle(&team4[0], &team4[5]);  
                    while(l<6){
                        S[0][l]=team1[l];
                        S[1][l]=team2[l];
                        S[2][l]=team3[l];
                        S[3][l]=team4[l];
                        l++;  //++l;
                    }
                    flag=true; 
                }
                l=0;
                if(flag=true){
                    break;
                }
                k++;   //++k;
            }   //while(k<4) loop ends
            k=0;
            if(flag=true){
                break;
            }
         j++;
        }       //while(j<4) loop ends
        j=0;
        i++;
    if(flag=true){
        i=0;
        j=0;
        k=0;
        l=0;
        flag=false;
    }
}               //while(i<6) loop ends

    std::cout << S[0][0] <<".."<< S[0][1] <<".."<< S[0][2] <<".."<< S[0][3] <<".."<< S[0][4] <<".."<< S[0][5] <<std::endl;  //line 0
    std::cout << S[1][0] <<".."<< S[1][1] <<".."<< S[1][2] <<".."<< S[1][3] <<".."<< S[1][4] <<".."<< S[1][5] <<std::endl;
    std::cout << S[2][0] <<".."<< S[2][1] <<".."<< S[2][2] <<".."<< S[2][3] <<".."<< S[2][4] <<".."<< S[2][5] <<std::endl;
    std::cout << S[3][0] <<".."<< S[3][1] <<".."<< S[3][2] <<".."<< S[3][3] <<".."<< S[3][4] <<".."<< S[3][5] <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're comparing. Each array after shuffling represents the team's schedule. In what way does it represent the schedule? Is it number of days offset?

Comment: Given a set of arrays with random integers, you want to return ______.

Comment: @John My bad. To clarify, the arrays are the matches a team going to take, in that order. Each 1st/2nd/3rd...6th match of the teams plays at the same week(time). It will take 6 weeks(matches) to complete the tournament. By the way, by "return_____" did you mean to return the valid teams arrangements in the end?

Comment: For somebody who's not sports-literate, what does it mean for team1 to take the -4 match, or the -3 match?

Comment: A minus value means a team will be playing away from home against another, which means the other team will be playing at home against said team. For example, now we have team 2 and 4 to match @ week3, with team2 playing away form their base to team4's, so the 3rd element for array team2 will be "-4", while team4 assigned "2". My explaination is just as clunky as my code, but you can find the exact problem described here, at page 2: Problem Description(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225700038_A_simulated_annealing_approach_to_the_traveling_tournament_problem)

Comment: No your explanation makes sense, thank you.

Comment: So your code is supposed to make sure that, for example, if team1 is scheduled to play team4 at team4's stadium in week 0, then team4 should ALSO be scheduled to play team1 at team4's stadium in week 0? So the team1 array would be `{-4, ......}` and team4 array should be `{1, .......}`?

Comment: Oh I found a bug. I don't know what's happening with everything in your code, I honestly can't follow it, but the various places where you write `if(flag=true)` should be `if(flag == true)`. The former is an assignment, and will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Thanks @John. Got to review C++ basics again. flag==true fixes that!